# @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER) vs ManagementServerProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

**Question1:** In Spring Security, what exactly is the function

`@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)`

Spring Documentation States the below, but I am not sure I understand it clearly

> To override the access rules without changing any other autoconfigured features add a @Bean of type WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with `@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)`.

The ordering of various security features in Spring Security are as below as per my understanding (LowestValue i.e. Highest Precedence to Highest Value i.e. Lowest Precedence)

1. `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` = -2^31-1
2. WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter = 100 (Based on @Order(100) mentioned in Docs)

   1. `Access_Override_Order = Basic_Auth_Order -2` for *Security Properties*
   2. `Access_Override_Order = Basic_Auth_Order -1` for *ManagementServerProperties*
      `Basic_Auth_Order-2` = 2^31-7
3. `Basic_Auth_Order = Ordered.Lowest_Precendence -5  = 2^31-5`
4. `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE = 2^31`

**Question2**
Based on the ordering of various security features above, If I want to override default rules for both Management Endpoints and the Rest of the application, should I use

- SecurityPropertiesACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER or
- ManagementServerProperties ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER ?

I am currently using `SecurityProperties ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER` but based on the suggestion  [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8255) to get ACTUATOR working I need to enable `ManagementServerProperties ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER`. Which one should I override if I want both working ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Q1.  Question1: In Spring Security, what exactly does the annotation `@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)` do?

What it does is well explained in the documentation you quoted.

> To override the access rules without changing any other autoconfigured features add a @Bean of type WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with `@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)`.

**But then `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, which has `@Order(100)`, takes higher priority.**

No.

You should be careful about this part `autoconfigured features`. Using `@EnableAutoConfiguration` which is a part of `@SpringBootApplication`, a lot of things are auto-configured and `100` is not a auto-configured value but a hard-coded value on the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class.

You can find order values used for auto-configuring for Spring Security in `SecurityProperties` class and you can find out that the value of `ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER` is the lowest which means it takes the highest priority.

**Where are they auto-confitured?**

You can find that `@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER)` is used in `SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration` class.

**Then when is the annotation `@Order(100)` of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` used?**

For example, if you disable the auto-configuring by adding `@EnableWebSecurity`, the value would be used. As the value `100` takes too high priority, it'd be better to put `@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)` annotation in your custom class in the case.

#### Q2. Based on the ordering of various security features above, If I want to override default rules for both Management Endpoints and the Rest of the application, what should I use

Use `ManagementServerProperties ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER`.

It takes higher priority so you must use it if you want to override default rules for all end points. You can see how the values are set if you open the `ManagementServerProperties` class.

In `SecurityProperties`

```
int ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER = SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 2; // 39
int BASIC_AUTH_ORDER = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 5; // 41
```

In `ManagementServerProperties`

```
int BASIC_AUTH_ORDER = SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 5; // 36
int ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER = ManagementServerProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 1; // 35
```

In the comment, `39` means `21474839`, I've omitted the first 6 digits for readability.

Comment: Seems like SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER no longer exists. We could use SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 2 to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 16):

**SecurityProperties** no longer defines the **ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER** constant for the @Order annotation. However, Spring Boot no longer defines any security details if the application does, so we do not need the @Order annotation on the security @Configuration class and can be removed.