# Access denied for token revoke

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement token revoke using Spring OAuth2. I created this endpoint:

```
    @PostMapping("/oauth/revoke")
    public ResponseEntity<String> revoke(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
        RevocationService revocationService = revocationServiceFactory
                .create(params.get("token_type_hint"));

        revocationService.revoke(params.get("token"));

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

Github [code](https://github.com/rcbandit111/OAuth2/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/rest/TokenRevocationController.java#L23)

I tried to configure these permissions:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()

                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/revoke").and()
                .httpBasic().and()

                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

I can successfully generate OAuth2 token but I get always `Access denied` usisng this request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/oauth/revoke' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46cXdlcnR5' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'token=.......' \
--data-urlencode 'token_type_hint=access_token'
```

Do you know how this issue can be solved? I suppose that `HttpSecurity` is not properly configured but I can't find a solution for this problem.

Comment: Try this: `http.csrf().disable().formLogin().disable().httpBasic().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(POST, "/oauth/revoke").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();` On the other hand, define your parameters with `@RequestParam Map<String, String> params` is quite error prone, always is better indentify what you expect in every endpoint.

Comment: Taking a look to your code and configuration, you currently have a "mix of tries" about security configuration, ways to securize your endpoints, deal with Spring security funcionality etc Using that base is more complex to achieve what you need. My recomendation is create a new project keeping what you really need and want to use.

Comment: @doctore I have a question: is it possible to use `httpBasic()` authentication for  `/oauth/token` when user tries to authenticate and NOT to use `httpBasic()` when `/oauth/revoke` us used? I managed to solve the issue using `@Order(SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER)` Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63103742/revoke-oauth2-token-without-using-basic-auth

Comment: One of the principles of Oauth is precisely to use authentication to manage the resources, if you want to "avoid it" for an important endpoint like `revoke`, maybe you are searching "another thing" different to Oauth. Projects like `spring-cloud-starter-oauth2` are nice in some scenarios but when you need more and more customizations every time, basically you have 2 choices: **1.** Create your own security functionality **2.** Deal with the provided options of the "dependency project" you are using.

Comment: so in short -> I can't avoid `httpBasic()` for  `/oauth/revoke` and have `httpBasic()` for  `/oauth/token`?

Comment: kind remind, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to add `@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)` on your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` at class level.

> To override the access rules without changing any other
> auto-configured features add a @Bean of type
> WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with
> @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER) and configure it to
> meet your needs.

From https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M5/reference/html/boot-features-security.html

Comment: I get `Cannot resolve symbol 'ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER'`. Maybe because I use `spring-cloud-starter-oauth2`

Comment: I think you have the `@EnableResourceServer` annotation on your project. So check the `ResourceServerConfiguration` class, it is the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` autoconfigured and it has an Order of 3, any lower order on your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` will override that.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I managed to solve the issue by using `@Order(SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER)` configuration. By the way us there more suitable order configuration?

Comment: You are able to configure some endpoints on the `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`, on this method: `public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security)`

Comment: But if you want to manage even more you could take a look on the `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration` and the answer on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529743/ordersecurityproperties-access-override-order-vs-managementserverproperties-a

Answer (score 1):

```
.csrf()
.disable()
.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/revoke").permitAll().and()
.httpBasic().and()
```

will disable required authentication for endpoint `/oauth/revoke` and will get rid off access denied error response. You did not specify if user requesting revoke operation must be authenticated or not. Note that supposed solution must go before any authentication restriction on parent path. If there is for example

```
.csrf()
.disable()
.requestMatchers().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/revoke").permitAll().and()
.httpBasic().and()
```

It will not work since parent path ("/") requires authentication. In spring security authentication requirement must come after any unauthenticated sub-path.

Edit:
Since you are using httpBasic if you want user's to be authenticated when requesting revoke operation you could try to use curl with following option's

```
curl -i --user user1:user1Pass
```

Comment: for some reason I get `Cannot resolve method 'authenticated' in 'RequestMatcherConfigurer'` Any idea why?